# Python : having trouble finding multiple free ips in subnet

Tags: python, networking, openstack-neutron

I have written code to figure free IP in subnet. Code as as below,

Now there is one condition, Once we find the first free IP in subnet, there need to be certain consecutive numbers of IP should be free (buffer IPs) in the same subnet. once condition is satisfied, code should return the first free IP.

Given Code is working fine for this, however I am facing problem where I need to search for multiple free IP in Same subnet and respect above condition. In that case, in first iteration I am able to find the free IP and in second iteration I guess we should add the buffer IPs and start the search but not sure how to implement that.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
def ip_definer(start, end, cidr, ip_buffer):
    start_ip = ipaddress.ip_address(start)    #DHCP Allocation Pool Start IP
    end_ip = ipaddress.ip_address(end)        #DHCP Allocation Pool End IP
    net_cidr = ipaddress.IPv4Network(cidr)    #Network CIDR

    used_ports = []
    free_ip = []
    lap = []
    for ip_pool in net_cidr:
        if (ip_pool >= start_ip) and (ip_pool <= end_ip):   ##Makind sure that we iterate withing the DHCP Allocation Pool Start and End IP Range 
            scale_ip = port_crawler(ip_pool, ip_buffer, used_ports, free_ip, lap, end)

def port_crawler(ip_pool, ip_buffer, used_ports, free_ip, lap, end):
    if str(ip_pool) in used_ports:                  #### Looking for Free IP, Wher 'used_ports' is a list of occupied IPs.
        print "IP {0} is used".format(ip_pool)
    else:
        n = len(free_ip)
        if n == 0:
            free_ip.append(ip_pool)             ### First Free IP in the Subnet 

        if end == str(ip_pool):         ### If we hit the Last IP of subnet.
            lap.append(free_ip[-1])      ## Store Last IP of the 'Last free IP' found in Previous iteration.     

        if (n > 0) and (n < ip_buffer):         ###  Checking for IP buffer (addition consecutive free IPs)
            index = n - 1
            if ip_pool == free_ip[index] + 1:
                free_ip.append(ip_pool)         
            else:
                del free_ip[0:len(free_ip)]     
            if (len(free_ip) == ip_buffer):     ### if length of IP buffer is equal to length to lenght of free_ips, return first Free IP
                scale_ip = str(free_ip[0])
                return scale_ip
```

Also, just to explain a bit, below snippet works in first iteration, where it lap list will be populated with 'last free IP'. In next iteration, code should start looking for free IPs from 'last free IP' + 'Buffer IP' + 1 on words, that is not working infect i am not able to understand how should i implement.

```
if end == str(ip_pool):         
    lap.append(free_ip[-1])
```

Comment: Please see how to provide a [mcve] This is too much irrelevant code.

Comment: What COLDSPEED said but also: your code is, to someone else, just a meaningless bunch of variable names.  You haven't given their types or values, nor explained what they have to do with the problem.  Without that information, it's impossible to make any sense of your code.